# make Button action cover it's superview swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i need to make a button that fills it's container view and make all the view clickable, but i failed, it only make button content size clickable (which is the label size)

```
Button(action: {
       print("item Clicked")
       }) {
       Text("whyyyy")
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

i know i can reverse it by putting my container view within the button but i just don't like this style i need the button to be within the view
and i know i can make a tapGesture but i want to feel free like in UIKit

Answer (score 1):

You can use clear color content to make whole area clickable.

```
struct ContentViewNewTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Button(action: {
                print("item Clicked")
            }) {
                Color.clear //<--- Here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked! i swear to god swiftUI is so weird, i've tried a spacer before i make the question and it didn't work, i hope they make things smoother like it used to be in UIKit :(

Answer (score 0):

Just move `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` under `Text("whyyyy")` before before closing the bracket

Edit:
Also add the modifier `.background(Color.clear)`

Final Result:

```
Button(action: {
       print("item Clicked")
       }) {
       Text("whyyyy")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .background(Color.clear)
}
```

Comment: nope, then the clickable are will only be the text, the color within the button in Raja's answer did the trick